# Typescript Record<string, Value>[key] should return `Value | undefined`, isn't it?

Tags: typescript

Why `Record<string, Value>[key]` just returns `Value` and doesn't consider missing value? IMO it should return `Value|undefined`, rgiht? Should I log a bug on Typescript GitHub repo?

```
interface User {
  name: string
  age: number
  done: boolean
}

const usersMap: Record<string, User> = {}

//runtime exception: TypeError: usersMap[1] is undefined
const firstAge = usersMap['1'].age
```

Comment: There's an existing [suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778) for this, you don't need to file an issue.

Answer (score 24):

Adding this to your tsconfig will result in a TypeScript error for unknown keys:

```
"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
```

Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess

Answer (score 4):

I usually would define usersMap as:

```js
const usersMap: Record<string, User|undefined> = {};
```

A side-effect is that you can explicit assign undefined - beneath the possibility to call `delete usersMap['1']`

Another possibility is:

```js
const usersMap: Partial<Record<string, User>> = {};
```

Edit:
*if you use `const usersMap: Record<string, User>` you tell TS that usersMap will be an object on which every possible string exists as a property and the value of the property is an User. This is not that what you assign with the empty object. As you don´t restrict the property names (+deliver default users) you have to tell that the property access may return undefined.*

*`noUncheckedIndexedAccess` instructs TS "ignore some type definitions the developer defines everywere in the code". Thats why this flag is not enabled by default and will not in TS5: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49169*